# Multiple data inserts in same dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hive

We have customer data in a Hive table and sales data in another Hive table, which has data in TB's. We are trying to pull the sales data for multiple customers and save it to a file.

What we tried so far:

We tired with left outer join between customer and sales tables, but because of the huge sales data it is not working.

```
val data = customer.join(sales,"customer.id" = "sales.customerID",leftouter)
```

So the alternative is to pull the data form sales table based on specific customer region list and see if this region data has the customer data, if data exist save it in other dataframe and load the data to the same dataframe for all the regions.

My question here is, whether the multiple insert of data for the dataframe is supported in spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sales dataframe is larger than the customer dataframe then you could simply switch the order of the dataframes in the join operation.

```
val data = sales.join(customer,"customer.id" === "sales.customerID", "left_outer")
```

You could also add a hint for Spark to broadcast the smaller dataframe, though I belive it needs to be smaller than 2GB:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast
val data = sales.join(broadcast(customer),"customer.id" === "sales.customerID", "leftouter")
```

To use the other approach and iterativly merge dataframes is also possible. For this purpose you can use the `union` method (Spark 2.0+) or `unionAll` (older versions). This method will append a dataframe to another. In the case where you have a list of dataframes that you want to merge with each other you can use `union` together with `reduce`:

```
val dataframes = Seq(df1, df2, df3)
dataframes.reduce(_ union _)
```

Comment: ok, can you comment on the multiple insertion to the dataframe

Comment: @venkata See my edit, I think it should answer your question.